# how to connect rss feed to lock screen windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, rss, lockscreen

how to connect rss feed to lock screen windows phone 8?

what's the code and where to put it (like app.xaml or mainpage.cs)

I'm absolute beginner.

Answer (score 0):

There's fairly extensive documentation on [setting up lock screen notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207048%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and also on being a [lock screen wallpaper provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206968%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), on the MSDN website

Comment: Thanks for commenting, actually I did exactly what they wrote on those pages, step by step, however, RSS feed showing only on live tile, even though I have implemented the same code.

Comment: Is the app you've written chosen to be the detailed status app on your phone?

Comment: Also, how are you doing the tile notification - are you doing it as a local tile update, or via MPNS?

Comment: Regarding first Q, the live tile (flip) simple, pulls the last photo of the newest RSS feed, on the back, pulls the content.